# Webkit not working in Google Chrome anymore?

Tags: css, google-chrome

What I knew is Google Chrome is going to use blink instead of webkit, So what I want to confirm is future still able to use CSS with `-webkit` run in Google Chrome ?

Because I had few website and system also used `-webkit`

[Here is the Google Chrome news I read](http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2013/04/blink/)

Comment: Is already using Blink. http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/04/04/googles-blink-qa-new-rendering-engine-will-replace-webkit-on-all-platforms-in-10-weeks-with-chrome-28/ It's a big deal but nothing big to worry about for developers, for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the article carefully, Blink is the fork of WebKit . Therefore, the `-webkit` will have high chance continuing to work.

Comment: Also, as far as I remember they said that they won't throw out current vendor prefixes but only that new features won't be prefixed but instead hidden behind a setting.

Comment: Thank guys reply, What my concern is afraid my system and website CSS suddenly not working, since @Shiva Raptor said that will have high change continue to work in chrome, so I just maintain my CSS using -webkit

Comment: I don't know the original source but I read about that one on: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/04/30/blink-and-the-end-of-vendor-prefixes/ . @Oscar, prefixed is never meant to work forever. You will always stay responsible for replacing it with the final version when it's out.

Comment: @RenéGeuze you are right also, I will always stay responsible :) thanks